# Doubt about integration by change of variable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I came across an example of an integral by change of variable that reads as follows

Find $$\int_a^{b} \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(x-a)(b-x)}}dx$$

What they do is to assume that $a<b$. They claim that the convenient change of variable consists of taking the interval $(-1,1)$ to the interval $(a,b)$ through a bijection of the type $g(t)=\alpha t+\beta$.

Thus, if we take $g(-1)=a, g(1)=b$ we have that $\alpha=\frac{b-a}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{b+a}{2}$, then $x=g(t), dx=\frac{b-a}{2}dt, g(-1)=a$ and $g(1)=b$.

Then

$$\int_a^{b} \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(x-a)(b-x)}}dx=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt[2]{1-t^2}}=\pi$$

However, I do not understand the reason for several issues in this exercise. First of all because $dx=\frac{b-a}{2}dt$ was taken, then when replacing these values in the expression it is not very clear to me how they arrive to the final value of the integral.

Any help please?

Comment: It should be $dx=\frac{b-a}{2}dt.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Assumption $a<b$:**

Firstly, the assumption that $a<b$ is fairly natural considering that the bounds of the integral are, in fact, $(a,b)$. Consider a specific case if you want to see other weirdness erupt, say, $b:=2 < 3 =: a$;

$$\int_a^{b} \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(x-a)(b-x)}}\, \mathrm{d}x
\xrightarrow{(a,b)=(3,2)}
\int_3^{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(x-3)(2-x)}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

Notice how both factors in the radical are negative for $x \in (2,3)$. Accounting for that leads to simply replacing $x$ with $-x$, and then you get a situation in which the bounds are in the $a<b$ order again ($-3 < -2$):

$$
\int_3^{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(x-3)(2-x)}}\, \mathrm{d}x
=
\int_{-3}^{-2} \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(3+x)(x+2)}}\, \mathrm{d}x
$$

This is just the integral if we took $(a,b) = (-3,-2)$; so there's no real reason to not assume $a<b$.

---

**Constructing the (Right) Bijection:**

Next, constructing a bijection $(a,b) \to (-1,1)$ is easy enough; you essentially need a function $g$ that:

- shifts $(a,b)$ to have left endpoint $0$, so $(a,b) \to (0,b-a)$
- then squishes that interval down to length $2$, so $(0,b-a) \to (0,2)$
- and then shifts that left one unit

Thus we:

- subtract $a$
- divide by $(b-a)/2$
- subtract $1$

This means that

$$g(t) = \frac{ t-a }{(b-a)/2} - 1 = \frac{-2t}{a-b}   + \frac{a+b}{a-b}$$

If we insist on the form $g(t) = \alpha t + \beta$, this means

$$\alpha = - \frac{2}{a-b} \qquad \beta = \frac{a+b}{a-b}$$

> **Possible Question:** Wait, this is a bijection $(a,b) \to (-1,1)$, not the other way around. What gives?

What we're going to be doing is a $u$-substitution, or, in this case, $g$-substitution. If we want $g((a,b)) = (-1,1)$, this is what is necessary.

However, if we seek to replace $x$ in our integrand, we need the inverse of this, the backwards transformation. ***This*** is where the original transformation comes into play. It can be constructed similarly, and we have

$$g^{-1}(t) = \frac{t-\beta}{\alpha} =   \frac{b-a}{2} t + \frac{a+b}{2}$$

---

**The Substitution & Subsequent Algebra:**

So, letting $u=g(x)$ be our substitution, then:

- The bounds change from $(a,b)$ to $(-1,1)$
- $x$ becomes $g^{-1}(u)$
- $\displaystyle \, \mathrm{d}x = (g^{-1})'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{b-a}{2} \, \, \mathrm{d}t$

In particular,

$$x-a \mapsto \frac{b-a}{2} t + \frac{a+b}{2} - a = \frac 1 2 (t+1)(b-a)$$

and

$$b-x \mapsto b - \frac{b-a}{2} t - \frac{a+b}{2} = \frac 1 2 (t-1)(a-b)$$

Consequently, multiplying the two and noting $(t^2 - 1) = -(1-t^2)$, and using that to reverse the order of subtraction in one of the factors, we

$$(x-a)(b-x) \mapsto \frac 1 4 (1-t^2)(b-a)^2$$

and

$$\sqrt{ \frac 1 4 (1-t^2)(b-a)^2 } = \frac{b-a}{2} \sqrt{1-t^2}$$

Thus, summarily,

$$\int_a^{b} \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{(x-a)(b-x)}}\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{(b-a)/2} \frac{(b-a)/2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \, \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\, \mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} $$

---

**Final Step:**

And as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{ \mathrm{d}x} \arcsin(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

we have

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\, \mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
= \arcsin(1) - \arcsin(-1) = \frac \pi 2 - \left( \frac \pi 2 \right) = \pi
$$

as desired.

Comment: The solution in the question used the name $g$ for your $g^{-1}$ (and by implication, your $g$ is their $g^{-1}). Perhaps it has something to so with how they presented the general method for substitution. But whatever you call the substitution function, this answer looks perfectly complete to me.

Comment: Your answer got me out of a jam, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here provides a new aproach.

Note the identity$$\dfrac{x-a}{b-a}+\dfrac{b-x}{b-a}=1$$which inspires us to do this change of variable:$$\dfrac{x-a}{b-a}=\sin^{2}t,\ t\in(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}).$$Now,$\dfrac{b-x}{b-a}=\cos^{2}t.$ Thus$$dx=2(b-a)\cos t\sin tdt.$$Hence,$$\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{2(b-a)\cos t\sin t}{(b-a)\cos t\sin t}dt=\pi.$$

Answer (score 1):

Like mio,

as we need $$a< x<b$$

$$\iff -\dfrac{b-a}2=a-\dfrac{a+b}2<x-\dfrac{a+b}2<b-\dfrac{a+b}2=\dfrac{b-a}2$$

WLOG $x-\dfrac{a+b}2=\dfrac{b-a}2\cdot\cos2t$ where $0<2t<\pi$

$$\iff2x= a+b+(b-a)\cos2t=b(2\cos^2t)+a(2\sin^2t)$$

$$\implies x=?$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we treat the quadratic in the integrand by completing squares $$
\begin{aligned}
(x-a)(b-x) &=-\left[x^{2}-(a+b) x+a b\right] \\
&=\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{2}-a b -\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{2} \\
&=\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(x-\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

WLOG, $a<b$,
letting
$$
\begin{aligned}
 & x-\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{b-a}{2} \sin \theta \\
& d x=\frac{b-a}{2} \cos \theta d \theta \end{aligned}$$

yields
$$\begin{aligned}&I=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta} }\cdot \frac{b-a}{2} \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\frac{b-a}{2} \cos \theta} \cdot \frac{b-a}{2} \cos \theta d \theta \\&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 1d \theta  \\
&=\pi
\end{aligned}
$$

If $b<a$, then letting $x-\dfrac{a+b}{2}=\dfrac{a-b}{2} \sin \theta $ will yield the same result $\pi$.